# Stuck at add item image to sales order

Tags: netsuite

I am trying this method to add item image to each item in sales order, but I am stuck at script part.
I able to add script, but it looks like the script didn't run at all. I didn't get the link to the field.

I think I may miss some setup in script setup. Any suggestion to check it? Thank you very much.

[Script setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfTs8.png)

https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/97003/kw/add%20image%20to%20so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Script setting image, you did not specify the function name for your entry point. In other words, if you want to trigger your script after submitting the record you need to fill the after submit function field with the function name that you defined on your script.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.